# How do I pass multiple parameters (or pieces of information) through state with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Stripe has a state parameter that it returns back to me to verify

```
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_ABCDEFG12345&scope=read_write&redirect_uri=https://sub2.example.com&state=asdf1234
```

Which is great! But what if I want to get a few things back from Stripe when it returns? Can I pass multiple pieces of information to this parameter? Is the best way to do this by stringifying and object and then parsing it when it is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! By design you should not pass serializable data through an OAuth2 state parameter, as it leaves open a window where a malicious party could edit that data before it's returned to your application. You should use your own application's authentication state to verify your users' identity once the Stripe OAuth flow returns to your site.

It's recommended that you use 'state' as a CSRF protection, and pass any sensitive parameters through your own application:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#get-authorize